# IE9 Javascript Error :: Undefined/Null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, null, internet-explorer-9, undefined

I have a piece of JS (below) that in IE9 is giving me the following error:
***The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object***

In FFX, Chrome, and Safari I get no issues. Not sure whats going on here - still learning a bit, so be easy on me if it's obvious :)

Thanks in advance!

```
 <div id="sample-widget" style="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="widget.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LA_triggerOverlay() {
            $("#la-w-001-overlay").toggle();
        };
       $(function () {
           $("#sample-widget").show();
       });
   </script>
   <div>
       <a href="#" onclick="LA_triggerOverlay(); return false;">
   </div>
```

Comment: are you loading jQuery or defining `$` in a script that comes before this block?

Comment: Post the contents of the `<head>` tag of your HTML document.

Comment: As posted, you'd either get the error in all browsers, or none. We'll need more context. :-)

Comment: Updated the original question a bit...hopefully that makes some more sense

Answer (score 3):

In latest versions of chrome and FF [and maybe Safari as well] '$' is natively supported as a synonym for document.getElementById()

IE 9 does not support this natively, hence you get the error you stated.

However, as gentleman above points out, you maybe missing a library [most likely jQuery]. I would highly suggest to include jQuery in your page and try the code again.

You can reference jQuery easily via this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So if this is the missing piece, it should solve your problem.

Comment: how jQuery doens't go in conflict with chorme and FF then?

Comment: You can over-ride functions in JS.. so if you were to define a new $ function, it would over-ride the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you haven't included a script *above* that code that defines the `$` symbol (e.g., jQuery or similar). There is no default `$` symbol, it's just a symbol that's used by a couple of popular libraries (jQuery, Prototype, and MooTools primarily). Unless you include one of those with a `script` tag above your code, you'll get this error — in any browser.

Comment: Except that the question states that it works in FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @amnotiam: I know, hence my comment to the OP.